# Subscribe after Unsubscribe()

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable, angularfire2

I have an array of observables.

On my `ngOnInit()` method, I initialize my subscriptions.

```
this.lineOrdersSub[line.$key] = this.af.database.list(this.businessService.path + 'line_orders/' + line.$key)
        .subscribe((lineOrders) => {
          this.line_orders[line.$key] = lineOrders;
});
```

I also have a checkbox for each subscription. When the checkbox is ticked (default), the subscription is active (subscribing to new data).

When I uncheck a checkbox, I do this:

```
unCheckmethod() {
      this.lineOrdersSub[line.$key].unsubscribe(); //Unsubscribe to my subscription
    this.line_orders[line.$key] = null; // Remove the data I get after the subscription (See first code snippet)
    }
```

My uncheck method works well, but after I'm trying to start the subscription again with:

```
checkMethod() {
this.lineOrdersSub[line.$key].subscribe();
}
```

I get:

```
this.lineOrdersSub[line.$key].subscribe is not a function
```

**My question**:

1. How I can subscribe to a subscription after I `unsubscribe`? If impossible, Can you think of any other way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is correct. You're calling:

```
this.lineOrdersSub[line.$key] = this.af.d ... .subscribe(...);
```

which means you're assigning a `Subscription` object to `this.lineOrdersSub[line.$key]`. Not an Observable.

Then calling `.unsubscribe()` obviously works as it should. When you try to call `subscribe()` it fails because Subscribtion object has no `subscribe()` method.

You have to subscribe to the Observable.

Comment: Thanks martin, correct me if I'm wrong - I'll have to declare 1. Subscription, 2. Observable of the same element using 2 different variables? Also, Will I have to write again everything inside my on-init subscription?

Comment: @TheUnreal If you want to be able to both subscribe and unsubscribe you always need two variables. One that holds the Observable (that's where you'll call `subscribe(...)`) and another one that holds the Subscription object returned from `subscribe(...)` call. That's where you'll call `unsubscribe()`.